# Python read json response and append

Tags: python, json, request

I have developed a post request with requests module and I retrieve a JSON, this is code

```
headers_ = {'Authorization': acc_token}
    params_ = (('start_time', '2016-08-01T00:00:00+00:00'),('limit', '2'))

    r = requests.get('https://server.com/API/v1', headers=headers_, params=params_)
    data_ = r.json()
    json_result = (json.dumps(data_, indent=4, sort_keys=False))
```

and this is json result

```
{
"loc":[
  {
     "origin":{
        "lat":39.72417,
        "lng":-104.99984,
        "eta_seconds":null,
        "address":""
     },
     "destination":{
        "lat":39.77446,
        "lng":-104.9379,
        "eta_seconds":null,
        "address":null
     }
  },
  {
     "origin":{
        "lat":39.77481,
        "lng":-104.93618,
        "eta_seconds":null,
        "address":"10 Albion Street"
     },
     "destination":{
        "lat":39.6984,
        "lng":-104.9652,
        "eta_seconds":null,
        "address":null
     }
  }
```

]
}
now I'm trying to append into array the lat and lng value of each json items array and I have try with this code

```
for i in json_result:
        print(i['loc']['origin']['lat'])
        dict.append(i['loc']['origin']['lat'])
```

but I have this error
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

How can I retrieve the value lat and lng for each element of the array and append into dict?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `i['loc'][1]['origin']['lat']`. Since the `loc` contains a list of dictionaries.

Comment: I receive the same errore

Comment: When I put your JSON result into a variable and do `print(data["loc"][1]["origin"]["lat"])` I get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_result` is a string, because it is the result of `json.dumps()`.

You don't need that at all. Remove the whole line, and operate directly on `data_`.

(As a style point, please stop adding those unnecessary trailing underscores.)

Comment: I have try but the error is the same: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is this `for i in json_result`, which will return you each of the `keys` in your `json`. You can simply do:

```
for entry in json_result.get('loc'):
    do stuff here....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a different solution , if you are still getting error then you can also try regex to fetch only lat , lng part :

```
import re
convert=str(json_result)

pattern=r"(l([ng]|[at]).'):\s[-]?\d{0,15}.\d{0,15}"

match=re.finditer(pattern,convert)


print([i.group() for i in match])
```